# "Unknown command `;'. " when mirroring a Windows Server FTP Site

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ftp

I have a Windows server running Windows Server 2008 R2. I've set up an FTP site and a user account and I can connect to it and successfully download files using the Windows command-line FTP client from my machine at home.

I have a NAS running embedded Linux (BusyBox with FFP) and I've set up a cron job to run a script to mirror this FTP site down to the NAS. This script worked a few times but then I noticed that the data on disk wasn't getting updated, so I tried running the script from an SSH session.
The output from the mirror command updates the console a couple of times saying "Getting directory contents" and then it errors with:

> Unknown command `;'.

The script is as follows

```
#! /ffp/bin/bash
HOST='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
USER='UserName'
PASS='Password'
TARGETFOLDER='/path/to/local/directory'
SOURCEFOLDER='.'
LOGNAME="$(date +%F-%H-%M-%S).log"
lftp -f "
open $HOST
user $USER $PASS
mirror -P 2 -n --log=$LOGNAME --verbose $SOURCEFOLDER $TARGETFOLDER
bye
"
```

LFTP is version 4.0.7.

Answer (score 0):

The cause is the proably line break with user and mirror. If ftp client sends "\r\n" without entering any command, this can make issue with server, etc connection termination.

Comment: I've removed the blank line and I still get the same error.